# How to get result of google place API In Hindi/Korean?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, google-maps, google-api-php-client, ios8.3

I need to get Api Response in Hindi and Korean. I have passed languge parameter with(hi for hindi) and checking its response by simulator but it's result is always in English.

Here is Url that was made by me for getting Search places result in Hindi

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=28.580000,77.330000&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyAnAS2zrUGCxU5zp_JvuCrBWLwndv7rElI&name=BURGER&rankby=distance&language=hi

Please tell me if anybody has idea bout my question.

Answer (score 1):

See the description of the `language`-parameter:

> *The language code, indicating in which language the results should be returned, **if possible***

There is no guarantee that the results will be in the desired language.
When there is no translation for the desired language/particular place-detail available, you will not get it.

So your attempt is correct, but you may not get better results.

When you inspect the response you'll see that you get results in hindi(where available) e.g. for **Sangam Fry Burger** -> **संगम फ्राय बर्गर**

Comment: Thank Dr. Molle. I am agree with you but what can i do if i am making Localisation in my App? can you please tell me other solutions?

Comment: you may try to use a translation-service like GOOGLE TRANSLATE API